# Flipping a deck of cards: why do the cards cluster?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, friction

First let me describe what I mean by flipping a deck of cards. Fan a deck out, take the card on one side, flip it - then, much like a string of dominos, the rest of the cards are flipped and end up facing the other way. I have attached a very simplistic drawing below to describe it. The fourth drawing is massively over-exaggerated, but the phenomenon does happen: the cards are never as evenly distributed as they were to start with - they appear to gather up in clusters, which are themselves evenly distributed.

[image]

If this is done repeatedly the clusters get larger and larger till it is no longer possible to flip all the cards.

**Question:**

What is causing this?

Comment: What surface are you trying this on?

Comment: There is friction (as noted in your tag), and for polymers friction can cause charging, which will result in additional forces holding cards together.

Comment: This is purely a result of sticktion.

Comment: Very interesting observation indeed. The pattern in the cards reminds me of the [Devil's Staircase][1].  It might be worth investigating if the pattern fits that model, and if somehow the nonlinear dynamics of friction are connected to this outcome.                                                 [1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DevilsStaircase.html

Comment: My guess is that as the cards are flipped, static electricity is generated and as it builds up, it causes more cards to "stick" together.

Comment: @JonCuster Shouldn't that be an answer? Or you want more experimentation.

Comment: I confess that when I tried those tricks I could never figure how to do them (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6T1lYyW_ScA). And from what I could see from people that know how to do them, it doesn't really appears they have any problem... But when they flip it more than twice it seems what is described in the question starts happening. Could it be that the table surface helps not building charge in the first flip? Or is the friction with hands more important?

Answer (score 3):

Untested Hypothesis:
Instability

When all of the cards are exactly equally spaced each card's base would shift the exact same amount every time they are flipped back and forth.

However, if one card's base is shifted slightly, it would feel more force trying to displace it in the direction it was already displaced causing the base to be even further shifted during the next flip.

Initial slight protuberances will grow with each flip until flipping ceases to work because the bases are shifted so far that the tendency to shift further outweighs the tendency to flip.